# Is M.-Gladbach an abbreviation for Mönchengladbach in the Verlustlisten 1. Weltkrieg?

Tags: germany, world-war-1

The entry for Peter Rill in the Verlustlisten 1. Weltkrieg, p. 26217, lists M.-Gladbach as the location.

Is this an abbreviation for Mönchengladbach, Germany?

Peter Rill was lightly wounded. I assume M.-Gladbach is the place where the hospital was located.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. The place however indicates the place of birth or sometimes the last residence before being drafted. The date should be the birth date.

Comment: The transcription of the record below the image lists M.-Gladbach as the Ort (place) and is blank for the Geburstdatum (birth date).  The date in the image - 19. 8 - gives no year.  The top of the page has the date of 12 September 1918.  I guessed that date was the date of the list and that the "19.8" was the date of the injury in 1918. If M.-Gladbach is the birth place or last place of residence and "19.8" the birth date minus the year, this is not the man I'm looking for.  I think I have more work to do.

Comment: @Judi there are dates from every month of the year on this page, it is not related to the injury. Except for the status (killed, wounded, ...) most information on these list was provided to identify an individual.

Comment: In the last few minutes, I found the GenWiki for the list.  I believe you are correct. Thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Mönchengladbach was called München-Gladbach (shortened to M.-Gladbach) between 1888 and 1929, then Gladbach-Rheydt, then München Gladbach *without the hyphen*, then Mönchen Gladbach. Only in 1960 did they switch to their current name.

( [German source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140704143006/http://www.moenchengladbach.de/index.php?id=erste_anfaenge), [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/place/Monchengladbach) also reports the old München-Gladbach name. )